# How to combine two `GridCoverage2D` to make a new `GridCoverage2D`

Tags: raster, java, geotools

I was wondering if there is any GeoTools code example which combines two `GridCoverage2D` to make a third new `GridCoverage2D`?

I can find examples for reading pixels from `GridCoverage2D` or writing a `GridCoverage2D` to a file (as in `gs:StoreCoverage` in GeoServer), but I cannot find Java code for, e.g. doing an ***arbitrary*** math operation with two `GridCoverage2D` to generate a third `GridCoverage2D`.

Anyone know of such examples?

(I am only interested in, e.g. reading pixels out of a `GridCoverage2D` and then create/write to a new `GridCoverage2D`).

Comment: You can use PlanarImage (`image` property) operations if you want to use the whole thing, or do the operations yourself in a loop.

Comment: @BradHards Any pointers to how to write to a `GridCoverage2D` after doing the operations in the loop? This may be newbie question, but I don't where to find such samples/tutorials. All examples seem to create `GridCoverage2D` through a reader Thanks.

Comment: Can you say what kind of operation you want to perform, and what source data you're working with. If I'm going to have to write it from scratch, then it might as well be relevant.

Comment: @BradHards The operation is, e.g., to subtract two images (e.g. GeoTIFF source) pixel by pixel.

Comment: Have a look at jiffle and jaitools.